# Using the Washer Method to find the Volume.

Tags: integration

Using the **Washer Method**, find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs:

y=5-x , y=0, y=4, x=0 around the line **x=5**

To my knowledge, I believe the formula for the washer method is V=π∫ (from a to b) (R(y)^2−r(y)^2)dy

I am positive that my bounds will be from (1 to 5), however I do not know what the Large Radius and Small Radius to be. I'm not looking for the answer, just looking for what the set up to the integral would be.

Comment: It's probably worth while to try to figure out exactly why you thought the bounds would be from $1$ to $5$; if you can find the points where your reasoning went wrong, you might be able to avoid those mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch the cross section:

[image]

The purple line is the axis of rotation; so if using the method of washers, you would be slicing horizontally (perpendicular to the axis).  This suggests the outer radius (the distance between the orange and purple lines) is constant irrespective of the $y$-value at which the solid is sliced; i.e., $R(y) = 5$.  The inner radius is the distance between the blue diagonal line and the purple line.  This is $0$ when $y = 0$, and $4$ when $y = 4$.  So it is simply $r(y) = y$.  Therefore, a washer at a height of $y$ has differential volume $$dV = \pi(R(y)^2 - r(y)^2) \, dy = \pi (5^2 - y^2) \, dy,$$ and the total volume is $$V = \int_{y=0}^4 dV,$$ which I leave to you to compute.

As a check, you should calculate the volume of the enclosing cylinder, and subtract off the volume of the cone, and the result should equal the value you found through integration.